# Query num_rows, size, num_tables, default_charset, default_collation for all databases

Tags: mysql, sql, collation, information-schema

Right now I've been able to come up with this:

```
SELECT
    table_schema AS 'name_db', 
    sum(table_rows) AS 'num_rows_db', 
    SUM(data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024 AS 'size_db(MB)', 
    count(*) as 'num_tables_db' 
FROM
    information_schema.TABLES
GROUP BY table_schema;
```

And now I'm trying to figure out how to add the charset and collation for all the databases but I'm not sure how to do it.

I've figured out information_schema.SCHEMATA table has `DEFAULT_CHARACTER_SET_NAME` and `DEFAULT_COLLATION_NAME` columns and I'd like to add those to my above query. Also, I'd like to know whether there is any easy way to display the db size in Kb or MB depending the size (ie: like heidiSQL summary does).

Guess I need to make some sort of join between these 2 tables using `SCHEMA_NAME` but the group by of my first query confuses me :/

Comment: The charset and collation of a database does not control the settings for the table except _by default_.  Ditto for table settings versus column settings.  So, I question the usefulness of what you have asked for.  Another approach is to do `... GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT character_set) ... FROM COLUMNS ...`  This would show all the charsets _currently in use_ for each database.  Please clarify whether you really want the default or what is in use.  (Yes a `JOIN` is likely to be needed.)

Comment: @RickJames Actually that's a good point, what I'm actually trying to achieve over here is showing the maximum relevant info of all the databases of my servers ~20dbs per box fitting in little space (1 or 2 cmd prompts pages so i can see all the info at once). What you're proposing about showing all charsets currently in use for each database sounds like an even better idea, would it be too difficult to add to my query? As you can see my SQL skills are pretty much rusty ones, need to catch up with it eventually :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out it is best to do the aggregates and `GROUP BY` separately for each of the two tables needed.

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  
    (
        SELECT  table_schema AS 'name_db',
                sum(table_rows) AS 'num_rows_db',
                IF(SUM(data_length + index_length) > 1048576,
                    CONCAT(ROUND(SUM(data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024), ' MB'),
                    CONCAT(ROUND(SUM(data_length + index_length) / 1024), ' KB') ) AS 'size_db',
                count(*) as 'num_tables_db'
            FROM  information_schema.TABLES AS t
            GROUP BY  TABLE_SCHEMA 
    ) AS t
    JOIN  
    (
        SELECT  table_schema AS 'name_db',
                GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CHARACTER_SET_NAME) AS charsets,
                GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT COLLATION_NAME) AS collations
            FROM  information_schema.COLUMNS
            GROUP BY  TABLE_SCHEMA
    ) AS c USING (name_db);
```

(There is some potential for users to be confused by `table_schema` vs `name_db`.  Since one is the alias for the other, the two are interchangeable in *some* cases.)

You may want to tack `ORDER BY name_db` at the end.  You may want to say `WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA NOT IN ('mysql', 'information_schema', 'performance_schema') to avoid the system tables.

Note that `table_rows` is only approximate in the case of InnoDB.

Comment: Wow, this query is great one! It's worth a good bounty and a bunch of upvotes. It seems to me you're quite the expert with SQL, I wouldn't have come up with something like this for sure. Hopefully more people will upvote your answer, as it's high-quality content. Tyvm.

Comment: Thanks for the praise.  It took me a while.  As a bonus, I added a few notes.